# Android Textview content size

Tags: android, textview, size

Is it possible to have a TextView object containing text of two sizes?

We can change the color of text content using single TextView object using `textViewObj.setText(Html.fromHtml());` method. But is it possible to have text of two sizes in the single TextView object like below
[image: like this].

What I am getting is shown below. I have tried a lot but the text is of same size.
[image: like this]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have checked with Editext.Then i came to know that `Html.fromHtml()` does not support `<font>` tag.I use this code

```
EditText text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.title);
 text.setText(Html
            .fromHtml("<html><h3>hello</h3><h1>hello</h1>"
                    + "<p><font size=\"5\">Font</font><font 
                                        size=\"10\">size</font>"
                    + "</p></html>"));
```

It show different size text hello and hello but in two different line.But `<font>` tag value does not change any thing

[image]

Comment: Using the font tag I can change the color of the text.

Comment: using font we can change color but i do not think its possible to change TextSize.I will be happy if this gave you some idea.If i use <h> then its possible to change textsize also but it will goes to next line

Comment: Yes, it is not changing text size. My problem is textview textsize is 100sp, so the above "999" number is printed in 100sp and rest of text "mg/dL" is printed using Html.fromHtml() method and I dont know the text size. Now I am thinking of to take two textviews one for "999" and one for "mg/dL". What u suggest?

Comment: ok ..so now better to approach two text view.But i am working on it.If succeeded then i will update my answer

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9808/discussion-between-vishal-and-sameer)

Answer (score 3):

You ca use Spannable:

```
Spannable span = new SpannableString("bigsmall");
span.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(3f), 0, 3, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
tv.setText(span);
```

The same you can do woth color

```
span.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.GRAY), 0, 3, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

Answer (score 0):

As I know, for a TextView you can just change the whole textsize using the setsize() method.
Anyway, I would suggest you another approach: use two Textsize in a linearlayout, one after the other, in horizontal mode. 
In this manner you could change colors/size/etc for each TextView.

Edit: another approach, since you're using an html mode, is the following (maybe change with your html styles):

```
myTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>" + mNumbers + "</b>" +  "<small>" + mSpeed + "</small>" ));
```